# Mass Transit can't consume messages

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I am sending message to RabbitMQ with MassTransit. I am seeing that when I run the app in RabbitMQ UI I see the queue name and consumer but I can't see in the debug. I don't know why I can't consume the messages.

Sender

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(config =>
{
    config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
    {
        var uri = new Uri(builder.Configuration["ServiceBus:Uri"]);
        cfg.Host(uri, host =>
        {
            host.Username(builder.Configuration["ServiceBust:Username"]);
            host.Password(builder.Configuration["ServiceBust:Password"]);

        });
    });
});

builder.Services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true);
```

```
  "ServiceBus": {
    "Uri": "rabbitmq://localhost:5672",
    "Username": "guest",
    "Password": "guest",
  },
```

```
await _publishEndPoint.Publish<Report>(report);
```

Consumer

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(config =>
{

    config.AddConsumer<ReportConsumer>();
    config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
    {
        var uri = new Uri(builder.Configuration["ServiceBus:Uri"]);
        cfg.Host(uri, host =>
        {
            host.Username(builder.Configuration["ServiceBust:Username"]);
            host.Password(builder.Configuration["ServiceBust:Password"]);

        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(builder.Configuration["ServiceBus:Queue"], c =>
        {
            c.UseRawJsonSerializer();
            c.ConfigureConsumer<ReportConsumer>(ctx);
        });
    });
});

builder.Services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true);
```

```
  "ServiceBus": {
    "Uri": "rabbitmq://localhost:5672",
    "Username": "guest",
    "Password": "guest",
    "Queue": "Report"
  },
```

```
    public class ReportConsumer : IConsumer<Report>
    {

        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Report> context)
        {
            so on.
        }
    }
```